# Windows Batch Script Feeding Arguments

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-arguments, file-get-contents

Suppose you have a script that takes a couple of command-line arguments and dumps its results to `stdout`.

Manually invoking this script will look like this:

```
perl foo.pl arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Without changing the script in question, is it possible under Windows to take the contents of a file (e.g., `input.txt` is a multi-line text file with `arg{1,3}` delimited by a whitespace on each line) and execute something like this:

```
foreach line in input.txt
  perl foo.pl current_line >> output.txt
```

Right now, I just have another Perl script that does this, but was wondering if this was possible anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna say yes.

I searched the web with Google for `windows batch loops` and got this page: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/for.php.

I dug around on the site and found this page: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntfor.php#FOR_F

So it looks like the code would be something like...

```
FOR /F %%variable IN (input.txt) DO perl foo.pl %%variable >> output.txt
```

Comment: The syntax is a bit  different. Inside a batch file FOR /F %%a IN (input.txt) DO perl foo.pl %%a >> output.txt. At the command prompt FOR /F %a IN (input.txt) DO perl foo.pl %a >> output.txt